# Stagger animation does not work when switching to list of the same length

Tags: angular

I am trying to stagger the display of the list items.  I have a navigation bar with 3 categories.  For each category, I am listing each items with delay as below code.  When I switch from 1st category (with 5 items) to 2nd category (with 3 items), the animation triggers.  However when I switch from 1st category to 3rd category (with 5 items as well) and vice versa, animation is not being triggered.

```
<div [@catList]="items.length">
....

animations: [
  trigger('catList', [
    transition('* => *', [
      query(':enter', style({ opacity: 0 }), {optional: true}),
      query(':enter', stagger('200ms', [
        animate('1s ease-in', keyframes([
          style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translateY(-75%)', offset: 0}),
          style({opacity: .5, transform: 'translateY(35px)',  offset: 0.3}),
          style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateY(0)',     offset: 1.0}),
        ]))]), {optional: true}),
    ])
  ]),
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you are binding your animation trigger `@catList` to `items.length`, when the new length and the current length differ, as in your first case, from `3` to `5`, angular sees that it has changed, so the animation is triggered. Basically angular just does a simple strict equality check using `===` to see if it needs to run the animation. if your `items` array is not **mutable** (You are not modifying it directly, rather you return a new array for each modification), then you can just use `items` directly in your binding like this `[@catList]='items'` because every time you return a new array, the reference changes, so angular's change detection will kick in and your animation is triggered

Comment: hmmm, but when i am inside one category, i need to add to the list manually. now i lose the animation for adding each item manually :(

Comment: what i did is i add another trigger <div [@catList]="items" [@listAdd]="items.length"> to handle the manual add of items

Comment: Like I said in my answer, I was assuming you were not modifying your array in place, and it is a best practice to avoid mutating your data structures to avoid hard to find bugs